# Asp.Net 4.0 gridview to show Display attribute value

Tags: asp.net

I have been displaying list of some class in gridview with AutoGenerateColumns = true.

The class has nearly 70+ properties.

Now I need to change the column header of the gridview. For example, class has property called "ProductName" but in the gridview I just need to show "Name".

One way is to remove AutoGenerateColumns and denote everything as boundfield. But it is too much of manual coding... rather a data entry!

I was thinking to use Display attribute of the class property to be shown as the header column in gridview.

```
[Display(Name="Product")] public string ProdcutName { get; set;}
```

Is there any way to use Display attribute in Gridview?

Also suggest something else also...

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the RowDataBound event, where you can manipulate the values of the header text.

If you know that the index of the column will always be the same, you could do something as simple as:

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
{
  e.Row.Cells[ColIndex].Text = "Product";
}
```

Or, you could declaratively set it:

```
gView.Columns[ColIndex].HeaderText = "Product";
```

Comment: Where is the displayName value coming from?  Is it part of the returned dataset?

Comment: I am not returning dataset... its the generic list<product> and I bind it gridview with autogeneratedcolumn=true. We may close the question as I write bounditem in gridview for all properties...